# AWS Cognito User Pool disable login button

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am using AWS Cognito User Pools for authentication with Active Directory.

How can I disable the Cognito User Pool login button?

I was able to do it with Amplify, by creating my own login button and disabling the AWS default button. However I can not use Amplify on my application.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your App Client settings in cognito user pool settings, Uncheck Cognito User Pool [image]

If you need user pool for other use cases you can create another app client and use that.

Comment: Thank you , but the cognito user pool is unchecked

Comment: Are you using the hosted GUI? Where are you seeing this login as different user prompt?

Comment: If you are talking about when user has signed in with Azure AD and comes back to the page, that prompt cannot be disabled.